# Tarantool: limit/offset in index.indexName:pairs call

Tags: lua, high-load, tarantool, nosql

I need to fetch some records from space `users`.
This space has a secondary index `category_status_rating`.
I need select users with `category=1`, `status=1`,  `rating<=123456789`:

```
for _, user in box.space.users.index.category_status_rating:pairs({ 1, 1, 123456789 }, { limit = 20, offset = 5, iterator = box.index.LE }) do
    if user[categoryIdx] ~= 1 or user[statusIdx] ~= 1 then break end
    table.insert(users, user)
end
```

As I know, iteration with `indexName:pairs` does not support `limit` and I can just user my own counter. But what about `offset`? Can I use this param and start from "page" I need? Or will I iterate without any `offset` and pass useless records (about 100000) and start to `table.insert(users, user)` when  my "page" starts? 
Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just try if it does what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using offset, you can save your position (that will be last checked tuple) if you really need it.
e.g:

```
local last = 123456789
for i = 1, 2 do
    local count = 0
    for _, user in box.space.users.index.category_status_rating:pairs({1, 1, last}, { iterator = box.index.LE }) do
        if user[categoryIdx] ~= 1 or user[statusIdx] ~= 1 or count > 20 then
            break
        end
        table.insert(users, user)
        last = user[LAST_INDEX_FIELD]
        count = count + 1
    end
    -- process your tuples
end
```

or, using luafun (where `drop_n` is analog of limit, and saving into `last` is analog of offset):

```
local last = 123456789
for i = 1, 2 do
    local users = box.space.users.index.category_status_rating:pairs({1, 1, last}, { iterator = box.index.LE }):take_n(20):map(function(user)
        last = user[LAST_INDEX_FIELD]
        return user
    end):totable()
    -- process your tuples
end
```

[Documentation on LuaFun](http://rtsisyk.github.io/luafun/), which is [embedded into Tarantool](http://tarantool.org/doc/reference/fun.html).

Comment: Hmm...
But what if `rating` is not an unique value? Does it mean that records from `first 20 records` can be in `second 20 records` if I willll use `last` as position?

Comment: Then you'll need to count number of tuples with rating `last` that you processed, and (for example) use `drop_n`